# Argon vs nitrogen for preserving wine

Tags: food-chemistry, noble-gases, pnictogen

I have a question regarding whether argon or nitrogen is to prefer when it comes to preserving wine.

Specifically, I am interested in knowing if there is a difference in preservation periods.

Also, if there is a risk of them reacting with the wine, which might affect taste and smell?

Comment: I don't believe there is any measurable difference between the two.

Comment: Nitrogen is a lot cheaper.

Comment: Point taken. Yes, I guess that counts.

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/213903/behavior-of-two-gases-in-a-closed-container&ved=2ahUKEwjPqp6M9c3iAhUlmeAKHZ-RBWIQFjADegQIBhAB&usg=AOvVaw2YsvCQwvzCN89yiWoimoxJ Related discussion on physics SE.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers! It helped a lot.

Answer (score 7):

In chemistry, some chemical species can still react with nitrogen so argon is usually favored, but, in the case of wines, none of the two should react whatsoever.

In both cases, however, the high density of argon is an advantage because it will always fall down to be in contact with the liquid in order to avoid contact with oxygen.

By contrast, nitrogen would just dilute oxygen in the remaining air and just slow down oxidation, because air is already composed of 80% nitrogen.